# HTML Code snippets not working Visual Studio 2019

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have been tried to search for the settings in VS2019 about the HTML code snippets/Auto-Completion in Razor Pages/Views. It was working earlier however it is not working now.

Example:

supposed I type the following line of code in Index.cshtml:-

```
div.table.table-sm.table-stripped.table-bordered "press tab"
```

It should display the following structure:-

```
<div class="table table-sm table-stripped table-border></div>
```

I have only Resharper Ultimate installed on my machine as an extension. Which settings should I be looking at?

Comment: Check if it's really not working first. Select line, open command pallet, select Emmet:Expand abbrivation. If that works, check if this option also comes when typing. If not, you can set your own shortcut do activate this.

Comment: I have tried many steps, but it was working with VS2019 without any additional custom snippets. It stops the moment when I added some tagHelpers. There may be some settings that might have affected to lose this auto-completion feature. I have gone through whole settings could not find it, I cannot reset visual studio default settings as I have customized my settings and can't lose it. Therefore there should a way to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Resolved by repairing vs2019 and install ZenCoding extension.

1. Open Visual Studio Installer.
2. On the version you wish to repair, click More.
3. Click Repair.
4. Open your project in vs2019>Extensions>Manage Extensions>search and download ZenCoding.
5. Restart vs2019.

P.S: All of my downloaded extensions and templates were deleted after repairing.

You can try other methods as mentioned in this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-resolve-intellisense-issue-in-visual-studio1)

Comment: It does not make sense to fix a VS issue via installation of a third party extension.  In addition, the link you provided does not reference snippet issues or configuration.

Comment: @Rashad what i suggested was how i fixed my issue when snippet was not working. It is not fair to just down vote answers.  You could edit my reply to make it helpful for others. Anyways, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Zencoding extension worked for me thx